# Qual é o significado da palavra "quiçá"?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

Eu vi essa palavra sendo usando recentemente, e o dicionário disse que quer dizer *talvez* — porém, essa definição não bateu com o contexto.

Então, qual é o significado mesmo?

---

**Exemplos:**

- > [Correção do comentário a pedido de muitos: A pergunta em si já é uma quebra de paradigmas (quiça [ou quem dirá ou que dirá] as respostas!)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23534749#23534749)
- > [A pergunta em si já é uma quebra de paradigmas (quiçá as respostas!)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81446/quais-s%c3%a3o-as-formas-de-iterar-um-array-em-php-sem-foreach/81448#comment165396_81448)

Comment: Qual era o contexto? Até onde eu sei, é *talvez* mesmo.

Comment: @bfavaretto http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23534749#23534749 ou aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81446/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-formas-de-iterar-com-um-array-em-php-sem-foreach/81448#comment165441_81448

Comment: Acho que ele se equivocou...

Answer (score 13):

***Quiçá*** significa **’quem sabe, talvez, porventura’**; é um advérbio e, segundo alguns estudiosos, vem do latim [*'quid sapit'*](https://www.significados.com.br/quica/). **Não é uma palavra que se ouça com frequência na língua portuguesa**, pelo menos no Brasil, e nem faz parte do meu vocabulário habitual. Já utilizei algumas vezes mas sempre propositadamente, com o intuito de soar diferente ou engraçado. No Espanhol Castelhano a palavra *quizá* tem a mesma origem, também significa ’talvez’, só que é usada com mais frequência.

Alguns exemplos:

- Você será bem-vindo, basta ter assunto para conversar ou, **quiçá**, sugestões interessantes.
- Pelo ruído estrondoso algo deve ter caído do alto do prédio, ou **quiçá** foi uma colisão entre dois veículos.

PS Não aconselho que você use essa palavra rotineiramente no Português falado, ou vai acabar conhecido como “aquele cara que fala *quiçá*”.

Comment: Ambos *quizá* e *quizás* existem no castelhan, e são bastante comuns. [Priberam tem](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/quiçá): “qui·çá 
(espanhol *quizá*, do latim *qui sapit*, quem sabe)
advérbio
Talvez (ex.: *Ele é quiçá o maior poeta vivo*).”

Comment: No Brasil, é ou foi bastante usado em poesia. Pelo que observo, seja em espanhol ou português, o intuito é quase sempre expressar *"tomara que"*, uma expectativa de algo desejável, e não *"talvez"*.

Comment: @Caffé  No Brasil, "quiçá" tornou-se uma palavra tão pouco uisada no Português falado, que quando ouvida pode ser até interpretada como um pedantismo.  Uma grande parcela de nossa população talvez nem saiba o que significa.

Comment: @Centaurus Será que não é bastante empregada ainda no Nordeste? Nunca morei lá mas creio ter ouvido bastante as pessoas daquela região usarem esta palavra. Você tem conhecimento do seu uso por lá atualmente?

Comment: @Caffé "bastante empregada" certamente não. Por outro lado, nosso país tem dimensões continentais.  É impossível conhecer o linguajar de todas as regiões. (será que usam "quiçá" no Acre ou no interior do Piauí?)  Mas se fizermos uma avaliação conjunta da midia escrita e falada (que, com raras exceções, representa a região sudeste) e da nossa vivência saberemos identificar uma palavra que quase nunca é usada.  Essas palavras, por terem pouco uso, chamam a atenção de quem as ouve.  Se alguém as usa perto de mim, eu vou lembrar posteriormente que fulano usou aquela palavra.  Por exemplo:

Comment: @Caffé Por exemplo, as seguintes palavras chamam muito a minha atenção quando alguém as usa no pt falado: quiçá, deveras, estou pasmo, doravante, profícuo, etc.  E é dessa forma que as pessoas avaliam se uma palavra é pouco usada ou não.

Comment: @Caffé Não, não é mais usada coloquialmente em lugar algum do Brasil. É uma palavra muito comum de se encontrar em obras literárias, especialmente obras de séculos passados, mas nunca a houvi em conversas coloquias. Neste caso eu recomendo utilizar expressões como "Tomara", "Deus queira", "Espero que (sim/não)". "Se Deus quiser"...

Comment: Centaurus, fiz umas alterações superficiais (que eu me permito em posts que já cá estão no topo): itálico quando se refere (e não usa) a palavra, e apóstrofos para indicar o significado de palavra referida antes. Mais substancialmente, os dicionários dizem que *quiçá* veio do espanhol, não do latim. E o dicionário da RAE diz que é uma alteração de--vê lá bem, rufar tambores-- *qui sabe* ou 'quem sabe'! Outra coisa *quiça* significa 'tomara que'? Aqui em Portugal nós só usamos o *tomara que* em coisas to tipo, "tomara que não chova" = 'oxalá não chova'. Tu conheces outros usos, pelos vistos?

Comment: @Jacinto  Qualquer alteração feita por ti só vai melhorar o que já está escrito, tenho certeza.  Foi boa a tentativa de padronizar a sinalização das palavras, como o uso de itálico quando se refere mas não usa uma palavra.  Aliás, uma boa pergunta seria se existe algum termo para uma palavra que é citada mas não usada em uma frase.  Quanto a "tomara que", eu certamente li em algum site antes de responder.  Como não encontrei a fonte e nem eu mesmo conheço esse significado, achei melhor retirar da resposta.  Valeu!  (gíria brasileira)

Comment: Centaurus, acho que *quiçá* ainda se usa vira e mexe, sendo sinônimo parcial de «quem sabe!», como em «Joãozinho é, quiçá, o melhor jogador do mundo»  ou «Ela vai trazer amendoim, talvez batatinha, quiçá uma Coca». Ademais, tem este, que talvez seja má prática, «O cachorro morde? — Ele não morde nem ladrão, quiçá ocê!» ,talvez sinônimo de *tão-pouco/sequer* — não sei. Ótima resposta, por sinal!